# Is there any technique to know in advance the amount of training examples you need to make deep learning get good performance?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, training-data, conv-neural-network

Deep learning has been a revolution recently and its success is related with the huge amount of data that we can currently manage and the generalization of the GPUs.

So here is the problem I'm facing. I know that deep neural nets have the best performance, there is no doubt about it. However, they have a good performance when the number of training examples is huge. If the number of training examples is low it is better to use a SVM or decision trees.

But what is huge? what is low? In this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.03832v3.pdf) of face recognition (FaceNet by Google) they show the performance vs the flops (which can be related with the number of training examples)

[image]

They used between 100M and 200M training examples, which is huge.

My question is:
Is there any method to predict in advance the number of training examples I need to have a good performance in deep learning??? The reason I ask this is because it is a waste of time to manually classify a dataset if the performance is not going to be good.

Comment: Post this on [DataScience.SE](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @nouney I almost do that, however I think here more people will see it, so I might get a response. For me this is a real problem, in fact I've lost a lot of time doing manual classifications and I don't know if I need 10k more, 100k or 100M

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is: Is there any method to predict in advance the number of training examples I need to have a good performance in deep learning??? The reason I ask this is because it is a waste of time to manually classify a dataset if the performance is not going to be good.

The short answer is **no**. You do not have this kind of knowledge, furthermore **you will never have**. These kind of problems are impossible to solve, ever.

What you can have are just some general heuristics/empirical knowledge, which will say if **it is probable that DL will not work well** (as it is possible to predict fail of the method, while nearly impossible to predict the success), nothing more. In current research, DL rarely works well for datasets smaller than hundreads thousands/milions of samples (I do not count MNIST because **everything works well on MNIST**). Furthermore, DL is heavily studied actually in just two types of problems - NLP and image processing, thus you cannot really extraplate it to any other kind of problems (no free lunch theorem).

### Update

Just to make it a bit more clear. What you are asking about is to **predit whether given estimator (or set of estimators) will yield a good results given a particular training set**. In fact you even restrict just to the size.

The simpliest proof (based on your simplification) is as follows: for any `N` (sample size) I can construct N-mode (or N^2 to make it even more obvious) distribution which no estimator can reasonably estimate (including deep neural network) and I can construct trivial data with just one label (thus perfect model requires just one sample). End of proof (there are two different answers for the same N).

Now let us assume that we do have access to the training samples (without labels for now) and not just sample size. Now we are given X (training samples) of size N.  Again I can construct N-mode labeling yielding impossible to estimate distribution (by anything) and trivial labeling (just a single label!). Again - two different answers for the exact same input.

Ok, so maybe given training samples and labels we can predict what will behave well? Now we cannot manipulate samples nor labels to show that there are no such function. So we have to get back to statistics and what we are trying to answer. We are asking about **expected value of loss function over whole probability distribution** which generated our training samples. So now again, the whole "clue" is to see, that I can manipulate the underlying distributions (construct many different ones, many of which impossible to model well by deep neural network) and still expect that my training samples come from them. This is what statisticians call the problem of having non-representible sample from a pdf. In particular, in ML, we often relate to this problem with curse of dimensionality. In simple words - in order to estimate the probability well we need **enormous** number of samples. Silverman shown that even if you **know** that your data is just a normal distribution and you ask "what is value in 0?" You need exponentialy many samples (as compared to space dimensionality). In practise our distributions are multi-modal, complex and **unknown** thus this amount is even higher. We are quite safe to say that given number of samples we could ever gather we cannot ever estimate reasonably well distributions with more than 10 dimensions. Consequently - whatever we do to minimize the **expected error** we are just using **heuristics**, which connect the empirical error (fitting to the data) with some kind of regularization (removing overfitting, usually by putting some prior assumptions on distributions families). To sum up we cannot construct a method able to distinguish if our model will behave good, because this would require deciding which "complexity" distribution generated our samples. There will be some simple cases when we can do it - and probably they will say something like "oh! this data is so simple even knn will work well!". You cannot have generic tool, for DNN or any other (complex) model though (to be strict - we can have such predictor for very simple models, because they simply are so limited that we can easily check if your data follows this extreme simplicity or not).

**Consequently, this boils down nearly to the same question - to actually building a model... thus you will need to try and validate your approach (thus - train DNN to answer if DNN works well).** You can use cross validation, bootstraping or anything else here, but all essentialy do the same - build multiple models of your desired type and validate it.

**To sum up**

I do not claim we will not have a good heuristics, heuristic drive many parts of ML quite well. I only answer if there is a method able to answer your question - and there is no such thing and cannot exist. There can be many rules of thumb, which for some problems (classes of problems) will work well. And we already do have such:

- for NLP/2d images you should have ~100,000 samples at least to work with DNN
- having lots of unlabeled instances can partially substitute the above number (thus you can have like 30,000 labeled ones + 70,000 unlabeled) with pretty reasonable results

Furthermore **this does not mean** that given this size of data DNN will be **better** than kernelized SVM or even linear model. This is exactly what I was refering to earlier - you can easily construct counterexamples of distributions where SVM will work the same or even better despite number of samples. The same applies for any other technique.

Yet still, even if you are just interested if DNN will work well (and not **better than others**) these are just empirical, trivial heuristics, which are based on at most 10 (!) types of problems. This could be very harmfull to treat these as rules or methods. This are just rough, first intuitions gained through extremely unstructured, random research that happened in last decade.

Ok, so I am lost now... when should I use DL? And the answer is exteremly simple:

### Use deep learning only if:

- You already **tested "shallow" techniques** and they **do not work well**
- You have **large amounts of data**
- You have **huge computational resources**
- You have **experience** with **neural networks** (this are very tricky and ungreatful models, really)
- You have great amount of time to spare, even if you will just get a few % better results as an effect.

Comment: thaks for the answer. Sadly I expected something like what you said. However, you seem very sure. I'm a scientist and I'm not friend of saying never (never say never XD). Can you prove it???

Comment: It boils down to basic statistics. Due to the fact that you are trying to minimize the generalization error (expectation over the probability distribution) you will never be able to be sure that any kind of model work well on it, unless the sample is a nearly perfect representation of probability (which, on the other hand requires exponentially many training samples, as shown by among others - Silverman).

Comment: But I'm not taking about the model, I'm talking about the size of the training set. The most similar thing I know is the Akaike Information Criteria (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion) or the Bayesian Information Criteria that can me used to estimate a priori the number of optimal clusters in K-means for example.

Comment: this is about the estimators. Estimator is a function from sample to model parameters (like conditional pdf). AIC, BIC etc. does not matter here, you are talking about **how good will be the estimator**, this is something extremely different from just guessing some more or less valid value of one parameter in some model (like K in kmeans - in particular, AIC and BIC **are just heuristics**, nothing more, they will not yield **optimal choice of k**, even though it is a trivial question as compared to what you ask for). You are asking about **predicting the strength of the generalization**.

Comment: This could be a solution https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics) what do you think??

Comment: Bootstraping, cross validation, train/test splits. This is **just try and check approach**, nothing more. You split your data (in more sophisticated way but just split) into train and test - and check if model trained on one part works well on the other, this solves nothing (this is just "try and check")

Comment: @leijlot thank you for your answer. There is something I didn't understood and I have some questions. How can you prove that after constructing a N-mode distribution (which correct me if I'm wrong, it is adding more features to your sample), there is no estimator that can model your data??? Can you please give me some more information about Silverman? Finally, for what I saw bootstrapping is nothing like cross validation. I have just starting studying but what I understood is that bootstrapping is a way of inferring a model from a distribution by resampling data. (I continue next...)

Comment: Please ask separate questions to avoid discussion. N-mode distribution is not "adding features", I am talking about creating a true distribution "underneath" which you try to model, if it has more complexity then your model class you use - you cannot model it, period. For silverman - Silverman, B.W. (1998). Density Estimation for Statistics and Data Analysis.; finally bootstraping is the same as CV, you can use both to create a model, and both to validate it

Comment: (...continue) So in plain words, we sample a small part of the true distribution (the unknown, what I'm trying to discover) and make inference of the real distribution which is enormous. This is exactly what I'm looking for, try to estimate the likelihood of if a models is going to work with a small number of examples so I don't need to get a huge number of training examples, which is very tedious. Thanks for this discussion. It's very interesting